# Bash Script How to Make a Temporary SQL(Oracle) Table and Use It Later

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to create and use a temporary private table in Oracle through bash script and need to read information from it and do some processing logic in bash script and then write back into it.
However, an oracle temporary private table will get deleted after the session is finished, and the only way I know to make an oracle SQL query (by wrapping the SQL query inside bash script EOF statement) will disconnect the session right after a query. and i cannot make any other SQL query to access this table later on in the code. Do you know how to resolve this?

The code i use to create the table looks like below:

```
sqlplus ${username}/${password}${url}<<EOF
  CREATE PRIVATE TEMPORARY TABLE ora$ppt_temp2(
    id INT,
    description VARCHAR2(100)
  ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE DEFINITION;
EOF
```

learn more about the temp private table in oracle: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-private-temporary-table/

I hope to know if there is a way bring back a disconnected orcale session, or if there is a way to call oracle sql without disconnecting with EOF, or any other ways

Comment: You can execute a SQL script containing all the statements you need by using "sqlplus ${username}/${password}${url} @filename.sql" syntax, it will be done in 1 session. So either this is enough to solve your problem, either you have to give us a better definition of what you mean by "later"...

Comment: Oracle isn't like SQL Server in this regard... you aren't supposed to create and drop temporary tables at run time. Instead, you precreate them just like any other managed permanent object. Your bigger issue is that you appear to want to make multiple connections and work with temporary data. That obviously won't work. If you really need to make multiple connections and use bash as your programming environment, then you'll need to use a normal table so the data remains resident. But I suggest you consider using PL/SQL instead, which enables you to write a program that runs in a single session.

Answer (score -2):

Simply,

```
sqlplus / AS SYSDBA
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DE8A79BD-FAE4-4364-98FF-D2BD992A06E7.htm#ADMQS0361

And there are GUI such as DBeaver

Comment: Sysdba privileges should *never* be used for application logic or development. It is a critical security vulnerability.